# How to call PHP Variable in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to learn PHP and mySQL and I am stuck on a problem. I am trying to create a ticketing system for my website but I am stuck on how to place the autogenerated Ticket # and Date into mySQL.

```
<!-- This is for Ticket # ID -->
<?php
echo "Ticket #:";
echo '<br>';
$Ticket_ID = uniqid('ID');
echo $Ticket_ID;
echo '<br>';
?>

<br />

<!-- This is for the Date -->
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('m-d-Y h:i:s a');
echo "Date: " . '<br>' . date("h:i:sa") . '<br>' . date("m/d/Y") . 
'<br>';
echo '<br>';
?>
```

I know I would write a query to insert it into a table such as "INSERT INTO table (Ticket_ID,Date,etc.etc.) but I am not sure what to put in for VALUES since there is no name to put it in (there is no input required so input= text name = ??? ) such as VALUES ($_POST['Ticket_ID']); 
I declared my PHP variable, but I am not sure how to name it?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

I am finally able to submit my ticket form. However, my Ticket ID and Submit Date show as blanks:
Example: Ticket #:
ID58ede1275221e

Date: 
04:11:19am
04/12/2017

Submission on MYSQL:

Ticket ID: *BLANK*

Submit Date: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I was wondering how I can have it generate from the ticket and save it to mySQL?

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO ticket (Ticket_ID, Submit_Date, F_Name,
  L_Name, Email, Ph_Num, Subject, Priority, Description)
  VALUES ('{$_POST['Ticket_ID']}', '{$_POST['Submit_Date']}',
  '{$_POST['F_Name']}', '{$_POST['L_Name']}', '{$_POST['Email']}',
  '{$_POST['Ph_Num']}', '{$_POST['Subject']}', 
  '{$_POST['Priority']}',
  '{$_POST['Description']}')";
```

Comment: what information do you want to keep in database? you need to think about them first.

Comment: I would like to keep the Ticket_ID, Date, First Name, Last Name, Phone Number and Email for my database. So that when we pull up that ticket, we know who it belongs to and when it was submitted. So I was trying to make sure the Ticket# and Date posted in the database once submitted so the submitter can keep a log of the ticket # if needed to inquire on.

Comment: Does the user input a ticket_id or where does it come from? Please post your html code - just the form section so I can see why it's blank. Date is just a format issue I suspect, but will tell more once your html is posted.

Answer (score 0):

grab the variables individually first like this and perform validation testing and then write the INSERT statement.

```
$ticket_id = $_POST['Ticket_ID'];
```

Now do validation on $ticket_id.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO yourtable (field1, field2) VALUES ('$ticket_ID','$date',);
```

Comment: I have tried modifying the answer and creating a $query into my db to my table but it doesn't seem like it is connecting. I am not sure why when I submit, it doesn't send my query to the table. My database is connected I have verified.

Comment: Please update the question and add your php code of how and where you connect to your db, just leave out your password. Are you using xampp?

Comment: I have updated the question with the issue I am having now in regards to submitting queries into the table 'ticket'. I am not using xampp as I am not doing this on the localhost. I am saving the php and uploading it to a server provided for me.